# Existence of a basic sequence with basis constant $1$ in a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am interested in a problem motivated by the following theorem. A proof (and the relevant definitions) can be found in many textbooks about Banach space theory, see for example Corollary 1.5.3 in *Topics in Banach Space Theory* by Albiac and Kalton.

> **Theorem.** Let $X$ be an infinite-dimensional Banach space. Then for all $\epsilon > 0$, the space $X$ contains a basic sequence with basis constant at most $1 + \epsilon$.

Can we do any better than the above theorem? That is, does every infinite-dimensional Banach space contain a basic sequence with basis constant $1$ (monotone basic sequence)?

I think this is a natural question to ask, but I haven't made much progress so far and I also haven't found any references to this problem. Is there some easy counterexample or proof I'm missing?

Comment: Almost nothing in Banach spaces is easy.

Comment: I think you should give a short definition of what a basic sequence and a basis constant are. For me, for instance, it's the first time I've heard it.

Comment: @tomasz: The relevant definitions can be found in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis) on Schauder bases. The first chapter of Albiac/Kalton should also be a good introduction. I didn't add definitions to the question because I think the terminology is standard (so you can find the definitions by searching)

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen: Maybe it is, but people who are not familiar with abstract Banach spaces (like me) might still be interested in the meaning of this, if only out of curiosity. :) But the link works well enough. I had known what a Schauder basis is, but little beyond that.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen: But now I have doubts about your question. It seems trivial unless you add some assumptions, for instance that the basic sequence be infinite, or maximal in some sense. Otherwise you can just have a “sequence” with one element. If so, I would suggest first solving this problem for finite sequences of arbitrary length. Is that a trivial problem?

Comment: @tomasz: I'm not sure what you mean. Basic sequences are infinite. Specifically, a basic sequence is a sequence $(e_n)_{n = 1}^\infty$ of vectors such that $(e_n)$ is a Schauder basis for the closed linear span of $(e_n)$. The basis constant of $(e_n)$ is $\sup_{n \geq 1} || P_n ||$, where $P_n$ are the basis projections as defined in the wikipedia article.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen: I see, the sequence, as defined in the article, is supposed to be not only infinite, but also countable... that is a rather strange definition. According to it, for example, an inseparable Hilbert space does not have a Schauder base, which is counter to the idea, in my opinion. I've seen elsewhere a definition where the sequence can have arbitrary length. In any case, I think the casus of finite sequences is worth investigating.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an open problem. See problem 4 p. 220 in the book *[Banach space theory. The basis for linear and non-linear analysis. M. Fabian, P. Habala, P. Hajek, V. Montesinos, V. Zizler.](http://books.google.ru/books?id=5BDX2NNsqR4C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false)*

Comment: "Apparently". :)